# Why is within class scatter matrix in LDA singular?

Tags: classification, matrix, linear, discriminant-analysis, singular-matrix

I read that when number of data points are much less than the dimension of data, the within class scatter matrix in singular? Can someone explain why this is the case? For example, while using LDA for face recognition.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail as at the moment it is hard to see what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem with  LDA, as the number of measurements of each sample (i.e., the dimensionality of each data vector) exceeds the number of samples in each class. In this case, the covariance (scatter matrix)  estimates do not have full rank, and cannot be inverted. There are a number of ways to deal with this:

1. Use the pseudo inverse instead of the usual matrix inverse.
2. Projecting the problem onto the subspace spanned, like using PCA.
3. Use a shrinkage of the covariance matrix, i.e add a diagonal matrix to     the covariance matrix.
4. If you are using a library where you  don't have access to the covariance matrix add random noise to your data (not the best way).